# PHP: consulta com caracteres latinos não retorna nada

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou escrevendo um código de uma pagina que irá fazer uma consulta em um banco de dados usando dados em um formulário com dois inputs: matricula e nome.

A ideia é seguinte:

Se o usuário não digitar nada e clicar no botão de consulta, toda a tabela do banco será impressa, o que está funcionando, se o usuário digitar a matricula, a consulta será feita pela matricula, esta parte está também funcionando, se o usuário digitar apenas o nome, uma consulta será feita pelo nome, porém, essa consulta só está retornando resultados se não houver caracteres latinos.

Por exemplo, se o php mandar uma query

```
SELECT matricula, nome, turma FROM alunos WHERE nome LIKE '%JOSÉ%'
```

não irá retornar nada, porém, quando eu executo essa mesma query diretamente no banco, ele me retorna resultados, o que indica que o problema está no php, alguém sabe me dizer onde está o problema?

Abaixo está o código, a parte crucial é a função `imprimirFiltro();`

```
   <?php
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $banco = "lyceu_secretaria";

    $conn = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, "", $banco);


    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    if (empty($_POST)) {
        imprimirTudo();

        } else{
            imprimirFiltro();
    }

    $conn->close();

    function imprimir($sql){
        global $conn;
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            echo "<table class = 'table'><tr> <th>Matricula</th> <th>Nome</th> <th>Série e turma atual</th> 
                <th></th> </tr>";
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>". $row["matricula"] ."</td><td>". utf8_encode($row["nome"])."</td><td>".
                        $row["turma"] . "</td><td>" . 
                        "<a href = 'fichaaluno.php?matricula="
                            .$row["matricula"]." '<button type= 'button' class = 'btn btn-info'> 
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file' aria-hidden='true' style='color:white'></span>
                                Gerar Ficha Completa </button></a>

                        <a href = 'editaraluno.php?matricula="
                            .$row["matricula"]." '<button type= 'button' class = 'btn btn-primary'> 
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true' style='color:white'></span>
                                Editar </button></a>

                        </td></tr>" ;
                }
                echo "</table>";
            } else {
                echo "Sem resultados " . $sql;
        }
    }
    function imprimirTudo(){
        $sql = "SELECT matricula, nome, turma FROM alunos ORDER BY nome ASC ";

        imprimir($sql);
    }

    function imprimirFiltro(){

        $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
        $nome = mb_strtoupper(utf8_encode($_POST['nome']),'UTF-8');     

        if ($matricula != "") { 

            $sql = "SELECT matricula, nome, turma FROM alunos WHERE matricula = $matricula ";
            imprimir($sql);

            } else if($nome != "") {

                $sql = "SELECT matricula, nome, turma FROM alunos WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%'";
                echo "Resultados da pesquisa para: " . $nome ."<br />";
                imprimir($sql);
            } else{ //PERMITE QUE TODA A LISTA SEJA IMPRESSA SE NENHUM CAMPO DO FORMULÁRIO É PREENCHIDO
                imprimirTudo();
        }               
    } ?>
```

Comment: Provavelmente, o PHP não está passando "JOSÉ" para a consulta e sim algo como "JOS£¢&" ou sei lá. Soluções: abra todos os seus arquivos no bloco de notas e veja se estão como ANSI, se sim, salve os como UTF-8; se não, tente o encoding na conexão com o banco de dados http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php. Evite usar as funções do PHP `utf8_encode()` e `utf8_decode()`.

Comment: Usando o encoding na conexão funcionou, obrigado. Porém onde tem   $nome = mb_strtoupper(utf8_encode($_POST['nome']),'UTF-8');  tive que permanecer com o utf8_encode() , se eu o remover o php manda o nome como JOS?. Mas foi uma dica preciosa, percebi que para imprimir na tela não preciso mais usar utf8_encode, já que o banco já retorna o resultado do select nessa codificação, obrigado.

Comment: Corrigindo, consegui tirar o utf8_encode() de $nome, apenas precisei ir no formulário do html que estava com accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" , aí eu troquei para accept-charset="UTF-8"

Comment: Então, tá tudo certo agora?

Comment: Sim, e além de ter resolvido esse problema, provavelmente a dica que você me deu vai me ajudar em outras partes do sistema que estou desenvolvendo, muito obrigado.

Comment: Na página do formulário, é preferível usar meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8>"` do que o atributo `accept-charset="UTF-8"` do formulário. Evite ao máximo usar `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: Encontras-te solução? É igual á duplicata que está marcada aqui?

Comment: Não, não é uma duplicata, a minha duvida se refere apenas ao envio de uma query select com caracteres latinos, essa outra duvida é sobre esses caracteres não aparecerem na pagina, no meu caso eles aparecem, o problema era apenas a maneira como o php os enviava para o mysql.